# How to diagnose "The instruction at 0x......... referenced memory at 0x00000000"

Tags: c#, .net, memory, runtime-error

I am responsible for an application that has been known to throw this error.

`The instruction at 0x09537333 referenced memory at 0x00000000. The memory could not be read.`

Unfortunately I can't replicate it myself.

My question is, how do I go about diagnosing/debugging this? I have the memory location of the offending instruction, but could I possibly trace back to a line in my code? i.e. does `0x09537333` refer to the location relative to my application or is it within the OS (Windows 7 Embedded)?

Is there any other way of getting further info about this error? Are there any known common causes of it that I should look out for within my code?

Comment: You won't be able to find the cause of the error from just this - you need to  include pdb files with your exe so in the event of a crash you will get a stack trace.

Comment: Did your app generate a minidump file? If so you can load it into WinDbg and figure it out, it's a fairly complex operation though.

Comment: `0x00000000` is *null*: the code at  `0x09537333` access to null object or something; often the starting address is `0x00400000` (*check this*, Windows can well use another one) so the RVA (relative virtuial address) is `0x09137333` (providing that starting address is `0040:0000`) then use *pdb* or other debug info to map RVA to source code line

Comment: I say run a static analyzer against your code and pay attention to all places where it says "null dereference is possible". You have a bug there somewhere.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - Then is this different from "Object reference not set to an instance..." ?

Comment: @colmde: yes, it can well be "Object reference not set to an instance..." - reference is null, but the code try to address it as if it's not null

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - So what could I do to cause this error (`referenced memory at 0x00000000`) to appear (not `Object reference not set to an instance`) to get a better understanding of what causes it?

Comment: @colmde: these types of errors can well be *difficult to reproduce*; if it appears *somewhere* (not at your workstation) you can obtain starting address and map instruction address (that is `0x09537333`) to *source code*; then having examined the source code go to solution. I also suggest developing a debug version of the software: catch all errors and show *execution stack* in the error dialog on exception caught, so you'll have the idea what went on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved this issue - here is some info in case others have the same problem.

Did a bit more research and found that this Access Violation Error could possibly be caused by an error in a call to a unmanaged function / code (e.g. a dll written in C++) - 
`try... catch` wouldn't usually catch this error, but will do if this is added to the app.config file:

```
<runtime>
   <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

That's one possibility.

But in fact in my case the error was being caused by a thread running for an unusually long time on one form.

The form was closed before it had completed. At the end of the thread, it tried to hide a button on the form. Since the form was Disposed by now, the Access Violation error was thrown.

I fixed it by resolving the issue that caused the thread to run for so long, but also "just in case", added

```
if (this.IsDisposed)
{
    return;
}
```

...in front of the processing for the button.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever 0x00000000 is the address that can't be read, what you have is a null pointer dereference.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by :

> 1. Uninstalling problematic Software  *OR*
> 2. Update Drivers  *OR*
> 3. Follow instructions :
>      Right-clicking on the icon of My Computer then head to the Advanced
>      tab and click on Settings you can find under Performance.
>
>    Then go to the Advanced tab again and click the Change button under
>      Virtual memory. After doing these changes you may restart the computer
>      and see the problem if it goes away.