# Python QT application crashing from memory error, how to debug?

Tags: python, qt

I have a PyQt application that occasionally will crash due to memory issues with the error shown below

```
The instruction at 0X00007FFC450FA07 reference memory at 0X0000000000000048. The memory could not be read.
```

I personally have not been able to reproduce this error in any way. It has happened on the computer's of a few people I work with while running my application. I have looked and see a lot of questions for languages like C# or C++, and it seems to be a pointer issue. Since I am using Python though, these questions and solutions are not very relevant since Python does not use pointers.

Seen here: [C# example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743615/how-to-diagnose-the-instruction-at-0x-referenced-memory-at-0x00000000) the problem here is a long running thread. I do use threading in my application so I have been looking there. I have ran my application many times with the task manager open to monitor threads and have not seen any problems. All threads seem to close. If there is a better way to monitor this please let me know.

I am using PyCharm and my Python version is 3.9. I am also using Pyinstaller to create an executable version of the application. I have ran the program using the command line, launching the executable, and also directly through PyCharm and have not been able to see the error at all or debug it.

Is it possible this is happening due to bit related issues? Meaning that I am compiling my code using a 32-bit version of Python, could some computers have a problem with that? Would compiling with a 64 bit version possibly solve this?

Comment: Qt is made in C++, so it might be possible that the error lies in there. I'm not sure whether you can do anything about it.

Comment: I don't understand the point of your question. so everything works for you? but not with your people? the code would be interesting. you might be able to see where the problem is. but up to now you have only said that everything works for you and not for others.

Comment: @BanAnn that is correct. I have not been able to reproduce this error, this is an issue because we are going to be releasing this application throughout our network soon. And we obviously cannot do that with a memory issue like this

Comment: If the error is easily repeatable on one of these other computers, you could use the old fashioned technique of using output to a logfile or console to try to successively eliminate half of the code that is potentially causing the problem - effectively a binary search, which should converge relatively quickly.  At any rate, introducing a log of diagnostics might help narrow the issue.

Comment: I would also try and eliminate the python installer as a potential cause by running without it on one of these other computers.